# RelativeLayout fill remaining space

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have to display 3 button and on seekbar in same line with the order

Button---Seekbar---Button---Button, where three Button are with fixed size and Seekbar should occupy the remaining space, belwo code works fine except for first button, actually it is not visible as seekbar is laying above it.

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="#555555">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/playPausBt"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/seekbar"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_select_video"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_select_video"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/buttonImageBrowse"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="84dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonImageBrowse"
            android:background="@mipmap/video"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonImageBrowse"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@mipmap/image" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android:layout_toRightOf` on your seekBar instead of `android:layout_toLeftOf` on your ImageButton

```
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/playPausBt"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/playPausBt"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_select_video"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp" />
```